# Axios keep returing the old data after updating it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, rest, axios

So what I am doing is fetching all data after deleting one item but the response I get from the API is the old data and what made me more confused is when I tried the same steps with Postman everything worked perfectly. That made think the origin of the problem is due to axios caching. I tried to pass `new Date()` to the query as many people suggested in here but nothing happend still the same problem but when made the request twice one under the other it worked perfectly.

```
let result = await APIClient.get(url);
result = await APIClient.get(url);
```

but I don't think it's the right way to do it, if anyone has a better solution please enlighten me.

Comment: What are you tring to do?
if you call the same call twice, the data dont updating until the second call return the data.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is update the list of items after deleting one item. To do so, i delete the item then fetch the data again from the api

Answer (score -1):

This can be due to the header `Cache-control`. You can add the header in your APIClient or on making the specific request by passing the header
`{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}`

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: well after invistigating a bit more, I found that getAll API is been called before delete API that's why I get the old data so I used settimeout it's solved. it's temporary until I find a better solution